# string.endswith("") does not work in IE(not sure how to use a Polyfill)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, polyfills

I am using `string.endswith()` to loop through JSON objects and find out if the any property of the object `endswith` a `"Value"` substring.

After finding out if the the object property ends with `"Value"`, i am trying to round off the value of the property to 2 decimals which are by default 5 decimals.

Here is my code

```
var MyObj= [{"$id":"1","GeoName":"EAST","ReachValue":87.88221970554928,"ReachValue":90.71955219607294,"DepthValue":18.44377295716579,"ShareValue":16.732108234801206},{"$id":"2","GeoName":"WEST","ReachValue":87.88221970554928,"ReachValue":90.71955219607294,"DepthValue":18.44377295716579,"ShareValue":16.732108234801206}];
Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(MyObj)).map(function (e) {
            return Object.keys(e).reduce(function (p, n) {
                if (n.endsWith("Value"))
                    p[n] = Math.round(e[n] * 100) / 100;
                else
                    p[n] = e[n];
                return p;
            }, {})
        });
```

The above code works absolutely fine in `chrome` and `Firefox`, While IE it throws `endsWith` is not a function exception.

I found out for such issues pollyfills are used, which i tried and i failed. I am not even sure if i used the pollyfill correctly.

so here is how i did it,

```
function polyFillEndswith(searchString, position) {
            if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
                String.prototype.endsWith = function (searchString, position) {
                    var subjectString = this.toString();
                    if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
                        position = subjectString.length;
                    }
                    position -= searchString.length;
                    var lastIndex = subjectString.lastIndexOf(searchString, position);
                    return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
                }
            }
        }

Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BubbleObj)).map(function (e) {
                return Object.keys(e).reduce(function (p, n) {
                    if (n.polyFillEndswith("Value", "0"))
                        p[n] = Math.round(e[n] * 100) / 100;
                    else
                        p[n] = e[n];
                    return p;
                }, {})
            });
```

is the above code even correct? if not how can i change it to  achieve my objective?

Comment: They mentioned they tried it and it didn't work. I assume they meant they tried the code they shared. @MichałPerłakowski

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The polyfill function you have is actually for attaching the `endsWith` function to the native `String` object, which JavaScript allows you to do. It will allow you to call `endsWith` like normal.

Instead of wrapping it in a function, let it run right away, then just use the normal `endsWith`:

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
    String.prototype.endsWith = function (searchString, position) {
        var subjectString = this.toString();
        if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
            position = subjectString.length;
        }
        position -= searchString.length;
        var lastIndex = subjectString.lastIndexOf(searchString, position);
        return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
    }
}

Obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(BubbleObj)).map(function (e) {
    return Object.keys(e).reduce(function (p, n) {
        if (n.endsWith("Value"))
            p[n] = Math.round(e[n] * 100) / 100;
        else
            p[n] = e[n];
        return p;
    }, {})
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You implemented the polyfill incorrectly.

You just need to include somewhere before using your `endsWith` function.

```
if (!String.prototype.endsWith) {
  String.prototype.endsWith = function(searchString, position) {
      var subjectString = this.toString();
      if (typeof position !== 'number' || !isFinite(position) || Math.floor(position) !== position || position > subjectString.length) {
        position = subjectString.length;
      }
      position -= searchString.length;
      var lastIndex = subjectString.lastIndexOf(searchString, position);
      return lastIndex !== -1 && lastIndex === position;
  };
}
```

Line 1 checks whether you need a polyfill. On line 2, the function is assigned to `String.prototype.endsWith`, which means it can be called with `String.endsWith(searchString, position)`

Answer (score 1):

Given requirement you can use `String.prototype.slice()` with parameter `-5`

```
if (n.slice(-5) === "Value")
```

or `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` `/Value$/`

```
if (/Value$/.test(n))
```